# Multiple Questions Regarding Non-Binary Trees C++

Tags: c++, function, vector, tree

I'm currently working on building a non-binary tree that takes I/O to build the branches of the tree. I have number of issues I need to work out though and some pseudo code that I don't know how to turn into C++. For starters this is the structure of the nodes for the tree.

```
// Code for the structure of a node

typedef string Elem;

struct Node
{
    int nodeID;          // Node ID number
    Elem value;          // Value contains a string for each node
    Node* parent;        // A pointer to the parent of a node
    vector<Node>* child; // A pointer to a vector which holds the children
};
```

Here also is the header file for the Tree class. The root_ private member is a pointer to the root of the tree and the current_ pointer points to whatever node you're currently working with. Size_ is simply an in that is incremented with the insertion or deletion of each node.

```
 // Header file for Tree class

class AnimalTree
{
public:
    AnimalTree() { root_ = NULL; }
    ~AnimalTree() {};
    void currentNode() const;               // Returns current node ID & value
    void parent() const;                    // Return parent ID & value of current
    vector<Node> children() const;          // Return the ID & value of each node in current
    int size() const;                       // Return size of tree
    bool empty() const;                     // Return true if empty
    void root() const;                      // Get the root ID & value
    bool isLeaf() const;                    // Return true if current node is a leaf
    bool isRoot() const;                    // Return true if current node is root


    void searchNodeString(string val);      // Search for a particular node by it's string value


private:
    Node* root_;
    Node* current_;
    int size_;
};
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to use my node struct as input in a class function for a tree? And if so how could I implement it in something like a search function to find a specific node?
2. As part of a search function how would you index the child vector of a parent node? Or in C++ code, how would you search through each node in a child vector individually?
3. Is there a better way to use the pointers on each node to traverse the tree? I've seem to run into issues when moving from node to node when using the parent node pointer to the child vector of nodes pointer.
4. In C++ how do you traverse a non-binary tree? Whether it be pre-order or post-order.

Comment: `vector<Node>* child;` -- Why a pointer to a vector?  Why not just a `vector<Node> child`?

Comment: You say that `currentNode()`, `parent()` and `root()`returns ID & value but the return type is void. Also, if you const-quialify them, you will not be able to make changes to any node from `AnimalTree` class, which I think you don't want. @PaulMcKenzie: `vector<Node*> child` would be better because of memory reasons.

Comment: *vector<Node*> child would be better because of memory reasons.* -- And worse for cache locality.